# Слово "только" в произношении

Tags: фонетика

Не раз из уст довольно образованных людей я слышал произношение слова "только" как "токо", точнее "тока". Интересно, как коллеги относятся к такому варианту.

Comment: Скока, здрасьте и чеек из этой же серии укороченных слов. Отчества также...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос нормирования разговорной речи довольно сложен. Мы тут не можем договориться, что вообще это такое, разговорная речь с точки зрения шкалы нормативности.

Но конкретно, думаю, в очень быстрой речи такое можно принять, если не слишком придираться. 
Но в целом это, конечно, орфоэпическая ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Чего тока в устной речи нет!
При быстром произношении такое произношение может случаться, так как произносить лишние звуки лень. А вообще, я бы назвал это слово жаргонным, как, например, "клава", "велик", "телик" и т.п. Лично я произношу только "только", никак иначе.

Comment: А как Вы говорите "что?" Каюсь, у меня иногда получается "чё?"

Comment: Я бы сказал: "Чо!"